# How do I query a three-level structure in two joined tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

There are two tables,
Table A  has a three-level structure that looks like

```
 

|    id    |   name    |  level   | up_level_id |
| :------- | :-------: | :------: |  ----------:|
|      1   | lv1_name1 |     1    |   null      |
|      2   | lv1_name2 |     1    |   null      |
|      3   | lv2_name1 |     2    |   1         |
|      4   | lv2_name2 |     2    |   2         |
|      5   | lv3_name1 |     3    |   3         |
|      6   | lv3_name2 |     3    |   3         |
|      7   | lv3_name3 |     3    |   4         |
|      8   | lv3_name4 |     3    |   4         |
```

---

Table B looks like

```
| amount   |    org_id    |
| -------- | --------     |
| 12,000   |      5       |
| 15,000   |      6       |
| 20,000   |      7       |
| 18,000   |      8       |
```

Table A and Table B can be joined on A.id=B.org_id, but they are all at the level-3 of Table A（Only level-3 has their amount）

I want to query the top-level name,level-1 name, and the summary amount that looks like

```
| sum_amount |  top_lvl_name |
| --------   | --------      |
| 27,000     |   lv1_name1   |
| 38,000     |   lv1_name2   |
```

For Testing, I have already accomplished the query of the level-1 name from the level-3 id in TableA

The SQL is as follows

```
SELECT name
FROM TableA
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT up_level_id
    FROM Table A
    WHERE id IN (
        SELECT up_level_id
        FROM Table A
        WHERE id=5) --query the id:5's top-level  name
    );
```

But when I join these two tables as follows, it goes wrong

```
SELECT sum(amount) AS sum_amount, name AS top_lvl_name
FROM TableA, TableB
WHERE id = org_id
AND id IN (
    SELECT up_level_id
    FROM TableA
    WHERE id IN (
        SELECT up_level_id
        FROM TableA
        WHERE TableA.id IN(
            SELECT org_id
            FROM TABLEB
            )
        )
    );
```

I get nothing as above
What can I do to make this query to be correct?

Thanks for everyone's answer and comment.

Comment: Please share more details, like the table structure, sample input data, and the expected output. Also, share how your problem is related to [tag:impala] or remove that tag

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I find it very difficult to query the result as I wish. So, I've come up with a shortcut——create a new table that a three-level structure recorded horizontally, which looks like

```
| lv1_id   | lv2_name  | lv2_id   |   lv2_name  | lv3_id   |   lv3_name  |
| :------- | :-------: | :------: | :----------:| :------: | :----------:|    
|      1   | lv1_name1 |     3    | lv2_name1   |    5     |  lv3_name1  | 
|      1   | lv1_name1 |     3    | lv2_name1   |    6     |  lv3_name2  | 
|      2   | lv1_name2 |     4    | lv2_name1   |    7     |  lv3_name3  | 
|      2   | lv1_name2 |     4    | lv2_name1   |    8     |  lv3_name4  |
```

As above,I can easily connect two tables

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).